# Published app and Google Play compatibility

Tags: android, compatibility, device

I've just put my first app on Google Play, and the phone I developed on was listed as not compatible. After some research I added these lines to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
```

After updating the apk on the app store, my device shows as compatible in the list of compatible devices, but incompatible on the app's Google Play page. It won't let me install to my phone. Here are pictures:

[image]

[image]

How can I get this solved?

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mypackage"
      android:versionCode="3"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.mypackage.Activity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />

</manifest>

package: name='com.mypackage' versionCode='3' versionName='1.0'
sdkVersion:'13'
targetSdkVersion:'13'
application-label:'My Package'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application: label='My Package' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.mypackage.MyPackage'  label='My Package' icon=''
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_SMS'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_CONTACTS'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.telephony'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
main
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240'
```

Comment: Could you post your whole `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Updated with AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I couldn't think of any clue. Could you please have a look at section [Testing the features required by your application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html), at post the `appt` logs again?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Edited in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Your min SDK version is set to 13 (Honeycomb MR2). Unless your SG2 is on ICS or above, it will be incompatible.

Unless you rely on new API features, you could drop down your min SDK version to 8 or 9(froyo/gingerbread).

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Comment: My SG2 is on ICS, and it runs fine on my phone when installed from eclipse or a debugging signed apk. However, the app does crash for gingerbread when I lower the minsdk at the moment (not worried about this for now).

Comment: But your target SDK version is set to 13, ICS is 14.

If you keep your minimum at 13 and raise your target to 16, this should fix the issue.

Comment: Tried this, and the problem persists. It seems that it could be a problem with my phone since friends with ICS can see it in the marketplace. Even though my phone is listed as compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It shows up as compatible now. I'm 90% sure the issue was Copy Protection. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

You can try so set the minSDKVersion to 7 or 8

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

13 is quite high. I am not sure but I think 7 or 8 is Android 2.1

Comment: My app was crashing on gingerbread for some reason which is why it's set to 13. I think it had to do with something in my custom expandable list adapter class. I plan on doing more debugging on that soon.